# How to get number of attempts to unlock phone

Tags: android

I want to develop an app and I need to get the number of failed attempts to unlock the phone. I can't find any resources about this subject. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Android Device Administrator API's to get the unsuccessful attempt count. Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code.

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

Context mContext;

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    super.onEnabled(ctxt, intent);      
}

@Override
public void onPasswordChanged(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
}

@Override
public void onPasswordFailed(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("", "pass failed");       
}

@Override
public void onPasswordSucceeded(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {        
}
```

}

Also you need to add this in manifest.

```
 <receiver
        android:name="yourpackage.AdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And use this to call the intent for activating device admin.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                                intent.putExtra(
                                        DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                                        cn);
                                intent.putExtra(
                                        DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                                        "xyz");
                                startActivity(intent);
```

You can maintain one counter that will be incremented in `onPasswordFailed()`.